# Can I cache jquery .map files?

Tags: jquery

I have a drupal site using jquery 1.10 which loads the file jquery-1.10.2.min.map.

Is it possible to cache this file on the client side? It's accounting for 70% of the total page load time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the .map file is purely for debugging, and you have to enable its use in Chrome. See here: http://www.elijahmanor.com/the-magic-of-the-jquery-1-9-source-map/

Your customers who haven't enabled the map file in Chrome won't be loading it. Try it in another browser or on another non-dev machine.